# invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)

Tags: c#, firebird

День добрый с толкнулся с одной проблемой.

Пишу программу на c# работающая с firebird 3.0
написал сделал релиз приложения запускаю его и появляется ошибка

"This transaction has completed and it is no longer usable "
после токо как попытался определить от куда ошибка получил что 
ошибка в ошибка в в первом ExecuteReader который выполняется

то есть  при первом ExecuteReader который выполняется
( не важно вызову я авторизацию или шифрование или что либо еще, ошибка будет в любом методе который выполняется первым )

сейчас когда убрал все лишнее постоянной ошибкой является

"invalid transaction handle (expecting explicit transaction start)"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Через debug эта ошибка не появляется все работает стабильно, но если запускаю reliz ошибка.

если продолжить то дальнейшие методы выполняются.

Вызываю ХП

ConnectDB CDB = new ConnectDB();

```
        FbConnection con = new FbConnection();
        con = CDB.fb;

        FbTransaction fbt = con.BeginTransaction();

        FbCommand SelectSQL = new FbCommand("SELECT * FROM USERS(@log,@pass,@roles)", con,fbt);
        SelectSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("log", login);
        SelectSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("pass", PassHash);
        SelectSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("roles", 0);
        FbDataReader fbReader = SelectSQL.ExecuteReader();

                  try
        {
            while (fbReader.Read())
            {

                id = (fbReader["ID"] != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(fbReader["ID"]) : -1;
                Fio = (fbReader["F"] != "") ? fbReader["F"].ToString() : "";
                roles = (fbReader["R"] != "") ? Convert.ToInt32(fbReader["R"].ToString()) : -1;

            }
            fbt.Commit();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)           
        {
            fbt.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            fbReader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }

        SelectSQL.Dispose();
```

Comment: Публикуйте код на котором падает приложение

Comment: Убирал транзакции (на выборке они должны по умолчанию работать)   все равно ошибка выбивает,  fbReader  должен быть в try..catch